# Keeping GRUB Intact When Reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-7

My Windows 7 install got corrupt. I'm going to need to repair or re-install it.

If I were to go about it normally, Windows would overwrite GRUB and I wouldn't be able to access Ubuntu. How do I go about repairing/re-installing Windows while keeping GRUB? What process and steps do I need to follow to keep my dual-boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to follow the steps described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

So after reinstallation of windows you can restore GRUB with one of the above mentioned ways.

Comment: The link above shows a terminal command that many try from live install. But when it says working system that is from inside the working system. You need to follow link which has added command to also mount partition first. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal